# How to display image Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have uploaded an image through a form and successfully stored it in a uploads directory and I have also successfully stored the full path of the image in my database.

But I am facing a problem with showing the image in view :

view :

```
                 <div class="deal-top-top">
        <?php foreach($getAll as $rec) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-3 top-deal-top">
                <div class=" top-deal">
                    <a href="single.html" class="mask"><img src="<?php echo base_url('upload/screenshoot/').$rec->ss;?>"class="img-responsive zoom-img" alt=""></a>
                 <span class="four"><?php echo $rec->data_kategori;?></span>
                    <div class="deal-bottom">
                        <div class="top-deal1">
                            <h5><a href="single.html"><?php echo $rec->nama_aplikasi;?></a></h5>
                            <p>Instansi: <?php echo $rec->nama_instansi;?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="top-deal2">
                            <a href="single.html" class="hvr-sweep-to-right more">More</a>
                        </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
             <?php } ?>  
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
```

upload/screenshoot is uploads directory path, ss is the data name in database..

Controller

```
    $this->load->view('produk_view',['getKategori' =>$getKategori,'getAll' =>$getAll]);
```

**if test with array :**

ss is the part of getAll query:

```
  Array
  (
    [0] => stdClass Object
    ....
        [ss] => 1487492623549.PNG
    ....
    )
```

**Error :**

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Thank you

Comment: i have updated the answer.Follow the way hope it works.

Comment: I've tried the code, but the image does not display ..

Comment: are you getting image value on `echo $rec->ss;`.

Comment: Kurnia please notice that $rec->ss there is still the [0] => image.PNG

get inside the index 0 first so you can get the image itself and display it.
The error says that it cannot display or use the object in an HTML.

**How did you get the result from DB?**

Comment: did you try this <?php echo base_url('upload/screenshoot/').$rec['ss'];?>

Comment: problem is in your **MODEL**, please show where and how did you get **$getALL** ...

Comment: There is no problem with model, because when i try echo rec->ss (the name of image file) that work fine...

Comment: when i try this <?php echo base_url('upload/screenshoot/').$rec['ss'];?> it display error Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: check first you have image or not then try `<?php echo base_url('upload/screenshoot/').$rec->ss;?>`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my mistake, I'm open wrong directory... haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with `$rec->ss;` because you have `array having objects`.

```
   echo $rec->ss;//prints 1487492623549.PNG
```

**UPDATE**

in order to use `base_url(),` you must first have the URL Helper loaded. This can be done either in application/config/autoload.php:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Or, manually:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then set your image like this..

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('upload/screenshoot/'.$res->ss);?>" class="img-responsive zoom-img" alt="">
```

Comment: That work fine to display image name ( $rec->ss;) , but i want to display the image from path 'upload/screenshoot/ (which  name is from $rec->ss ).. What the code for this ?

Comment: where is your upload directory?in root folder or anywhere?

Comment: in root folder , folder upload/screenshoot/

Comment: try with `<img src="<?php echo base_url('upload/screenshoot/'.$rec->ss.');" class="img-responsive zoom-img" alt="">`.

Comment: did you load url helper for using `base_url()`.

Answer (score 0):

in your view/HTML side try using

```
foreach($getAll as $key => $rec)
```

instead of

```
foreach($getAll as $rec)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my mistake, I'm open wrong directory... haha